# Removing unwanted White Padding at the right side of rows in body on macOS' Safari

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

if you open https://cut-rate.ir in safari, there will be a white space at the right side of rows in website. with a few zooming in and zooming outs, it will be gone!

i couldn't fix it on css. how can i fix this?

the website is rtl, and it is tested on safari 11 and 12. no problem on iOS Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .container has a max-width of 1200px. See your style.css file on line 830. You should change that to 100%.

Also, all rows with content in them have an inline CSS which positions them 40px from the right. This should be changed to 0 to have the rows 100% in width and remove the white space on right side.

Comment: i found another problem now. the website width is too much. i tried to fix it by using 80% instead of 100% and using paddings. did not get fixed. how do i fix that?

Comment: Which part of the website should be to wide? I see no problems here.

Comment: it is fixed now and ok. but it's totally horrible on every windows browser! and i don't know why.